# How to manually create and load namespaces in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to manually create and load a namespace environment `foo` (without making an actual `foo` package), so that we can use the double colon operator `foo::test` to access objects in this environment?

The `attach` function attaches a list or environment to the search path:

```
foo <- list(test=123)
attach(foo)
get("test", "foo")
```

But this does give the user access to `foo::test` obviously.

Comment: So you want to use `::` to access objects in the environment instead of `$`?

Comment: Perhaps related: Konrad Rudolph's [modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules) system for R (not sure of what you're trying to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is possible with the largely undocumented `namespace` package:

```
library(namespace)
ns <- makeNamespace("myNamespace")
assign("test", 7, env=ns)
setNamespaceInfo(ns, "exports", as.environment(list(test="test")))
print(myNamespace::test)
```

Not sure how safe this is though. For example `sessionInfo` doesn't work anymore:

```
> sessionInfo()
Error in if (pkgpath == "") { : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: You can also check how `modules` creates namespaces: https://github.com/klmr/modules