# Dynamically registering an R namespace

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out if in R, it would be possible to implement the python-ism

`import VeryLongPackageName as alias`

(This essentially only serves to save keystrokes, but I think if it were easier to fully-qualify packages, there would be less painful masking to deal with in our lives.)

So far, I see that the `package::object` operator calls `getExportedValue(as.character(package), as.character(value))`, which in turn eventually calls `getNamespace(as.character(package))`.  This either tries an internal C function or failing that calls `loadNamespace`.  And there I am stuck.  I have not found any documentation about how to do reflection onto the registry of namespaces.

Alternatively, I wonder if it might be possible to overload the `::` operator, though I can't tell if this is a terrible idea, or not.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: ["import as" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24391251/903061)

Comment: Since there does not appear to be a "robust" way to do it (I'd be interested, too!), the linked answer's warning that this *"should only be used for interactive mode"* should be extended to read *"will produce unreproducible code"*, for anybody who does not also use this hack.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742927/how-to-manually-create-and-load-namespaces-in-r

Comment: I feel that the SO question I posted above best answers my question (as least as titled).  With it's a one-liner now to register an alias for a package namespace: `library(namespace); registerNamespace('ggp', loadNamespace('ggplot2'))` makes all ggplot exports available with `ggp::`

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice solution. You should add it as an answer to the marked dupe so more people can find it.