# Comparing development versions of an R package

Tags: r

**Short version:** I'm working on an R package, and I currently have a stable version. I have some updates to make, and would like to compare the updated version of the code to the stable version in the same R environment. How do I do this?

I'm new to package development, and I suspect dev_mode is helpful here, but ?dev_mode hasn't helped me.

**Long version:** Here's the main problem I have... Inside the package (let's call it `somePackage`) I have a function

```
foo <- function(x){
    y <- bar(x) # some other function defined inside my package
    y
}
```

If I simply duplicate `somePackage` in a separate directory to make a development version, then load both, R now sees two copies of `bar`, which creates a conflict. I cannot run both versions of `foo` and `bar` in the same R environment.

If I only had the one function, I could probably do something like `somePackage::bar` and `somePackage_dev::bar`, but in reality I have dozens of functions in `somePackage` and making these changes would be tedious and should be unnecessary.

The key thing here is needing to run BOTH versions of `foo` in the same environment so that I can quickly and easily compare the timing and output of both versions on identical inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by loading package namespaces into environments and then attaching and detaching them. You can see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391251/import-as-in-r/24392892#24392892) for more about this strategy. But basically, you can do as you say and then load the namespace for both versions with something like:

```
x <- loadNamespace('somePackage')
y <- loadNamespace('somePackage_dev')
```

This loads the package name spaces into the environments `x` and `y` without attaching them to the search path. Then you can just `attach` and `detach` to decide which version of the package you want to work with in the global environment.

Here's a trivial example of how this would work (just imagine `a` is a function from your package rather than a constant):

```
> x <- new.env()
> y <- new.env()
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
 [4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
 [7] "package:devtools"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"     
> x$a <- 1
> y$a <- 2
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
> x$a
[1] 1
> y$a
[1] 2
> attach(x)
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "x"                 "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:devtools"  "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"
> a
[1] 1
> detach(x)
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
> attach(y)
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "y"                 "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:devtools"  "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base" 
> a
[1] 2
> detach(y)
> a
Error: object 'a' not found
```