# The R equivalent of Python `from x import y as z`

Tags: r

In python I can load a specific function or functionality with:

`from x import y as z`

How can I replicate this in R?

For instance, I want to load *just* the `count` function from `plyr`, 
instead of loading the entire package with `library(plyr)`

Comment: You could do `plyr::count()`. This will give you access to the function without loading the package.

Comment: @Gregor: they're not quite the same. The question you reference is about importing an entire package under a different name, whereas this is asking how to import one function from a package and give the function a different name.

Comment: Agreed, Josh. I'll let my close vote expire and instead just say 'closely related: ["import as" in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24391251/903061)'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd probably just do `count <- plyr::count`, so I wouldn't have to bother with ensuring I get the arguments correct.

And you might want to wrap that definition in an if statement, in case plyr isn't installed:

```
if (requireNamespace("plyr"))
    count <- plyr::count
else
    stop("plyr is not installed.")
```

Also you might be interested in the [import](https://github.com/smbache/import) and/or [modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules) packages, which provide python-like import/module mechanisms for R.

---

Also heed the warning from the [Adding new generics section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Adding-new-generics) of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) (original emphasis):

> Earlier versions of this manual suggested assigning `foo.default <- base::foo`.
>   This is **not** a good idea, as it captures the base function at the
>   time of [package] installation and it might be changed as R is patched or updated.

So it would be okay to use the `count <- plyr::count` syntax if it's defined in a script you're `source`ing, but you should explicitly define a new function and specify all the arguments if you do this in a package.

Comment: Nice, why not in the `else` have `{install.packages("plyr"); count <- plyr::count}`

Comment: @dimitris_ps: You could, but I was thinking of a situation where my code would be wrapped in some other function, in which case I wouldn't want it to go off downloading things.

Answer (score 11):

`from plyr import count as count` could look like this:

```
count <- function(x) {
    plyr::count(x)
}
```

Simplified:

```
count <- plyr::count
```

More complete:

```
if (requireNamespace("plyr")) 
    count <- plyr::count
```

**EDIT:**

I was inspired by @eipi10's comment. I was unaware of `::`
Thanks @Joshua Ulrich for the suggestions!

Comment: I'd probably just do `count <- plyr::count`, so I wouldn't have to bother with ensuring I get the arguments correct.  And you might want to wrap that definition in an if statement, in case plyr isn't installed: `if (requireNamespace("plyr")) count <- plyr::count`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no directly equivalent functionality in R, though as the other answers have noted, you can obtain similar results.

The `library` argument both *loads* the package namespace and *attaches* it to the search list. As noted by [Joshua Ulrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271616/joshua-ulrich) it is possible to *load* a package namespace without *attaching* the namespace to the search list. Using `library` actually calls both `loadNamespace` and `attachNamespace`.

The distinction of *loading* vs. *attaching* is best explained by someone who has extensive package development expertise (the aforementioned Mr. Ulrich comes to mind) so I suggest reading further in [this write-up on namespaces](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) by Hadley Wickham.

Worth noting, however, is that you can use the `pos` argument in `library()` to define where you are attaching the package namespace, as explained in the [documentation for the library statement](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/library.html).

Comment: This isn't quite true.  Packages are *attached* or *unattached* to the search path in their entirety, but they do not have to be attached to be used. A package namespace can be loaded without being attached.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am a little out of my depth here; could you do an edit that clarifies this? I don't want to post false information on this and always tend to cross my wires on _attaching_ vs. _loading_.

Comment: Take a look at `?requireNamespace` and my comment to the OP's self-answer. Bah, I should probably just write an answer... :)

Comment: You are the expert here, but I tried to expand on it a little bit above to be more correct and to stem the tide of downvotes. :D

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this question looking for the same functionality and using the approach described above, wrote a quick function to generalize the idea. I wanted to post it here for anyone who came across this question in the future.

```
import <- function(pkg, f) {
  if (pkg %in% installed.packages()) {
    assign(f, eval(parse(text = paste(pkg, "::", f, sep = ""))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } else {
    stop(paste(pkg, "is not installed."))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `library()` function with the `include.only` parameter.

```r
library(plyr, include.only = c("count"))

# Okay
count(mtcars, vars = "cyl")
#>   cyl freq
#> 1   4   11
#> 2   6    7
#> 3   8   14

# Fails to find plyr::arrange()
arrange(mtcars, cyl, disp)
#> Error in arrange(mtcars, cyl, disp): could not find function "arrange"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There’s now a package which provides this exact functionality: ‘**[box](https://klmr.me/box/)**’.<sup>1</sup> With it, the R equivalent of Python’s `from x import y as z` is:

```r
box::use(x[z = y])
```

> For instance, I want to load *just* the `count` function from `plyr`, instead of loading the entire package with `library(plyr)`

```r
box::use(plyr[count])
```

It’s also worth noting that, unlike `library()`, `box::use()` attaches names *locally*. For example, to attach *all* names of a package inside a function without affecting the global search path, you can write

```r
f = function () {
    box::use(plyr[...])
    # use it here.
}
```

(`[...]` is tells `box::use()` to attach all names.)

It’s worth noting that as of R 3.6, `library` also supports attaching only specified names:

```r
library(plyr, include.only = 'count')
```

However, this still performs global attaching, it doesn’t allow aliases (i.e. I can’t import `plyr::count` as, say, `plyr_count`), and calling `library` repeatedly with the same package name but different `include.only` lists doesn’t work (subsequent calls have no effect). In other words, it does strictly less than the Python `import` mechanism or `box::use()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> This package is the successor to the ‘modules’ package mentioned in Joshua’s answer, but it uses a completely different syntax and has more features.