# Abbreviating a namespace in R

Tags: r, namespaces

Using explicit namespaces sometimes makes R code more readable. For example, I prefer

```
lubridate::year(x)
```

to

```
library(lubridate)
# lots of code
year(x)
```

However, if I use the function `year` often, the first option requires much more typing, especially if the package name is rather long.
Is it possible to abbreviate the namespace `lubridate` to, say, `lbd` so I can call

```
lbd::year(x)
```

This would save me some typing while writing the code, and at the same time give me a better indication of where `year()` comes from when I revisit the code later.

Comment: Does lbd <- environment(year) then lbd$year(x) works?

Comment: Not ideal, but yes, it works. Thanks!

Comment: See, also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391251/import-as-in-r)

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz I guess my question is a duplicate and can be removed ...